# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute SpringMVC

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, annotations

Unable to solve the below error, tried different solutions but still stuck at the same error, please help. I have seen a lot of similar posts but nothing is working for me. So I will post it again with my code samples. I am new to Spring MVC and trying to make a simple form to add products to the database. But I am getting "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'product' available as request attribute" again and again. Below is the controller and the jsp file:

```
    Controller:

    package com.me.secretsanta.controller;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    import com.me.secretsanta.dao.ProductDAO;
    import com.me.secretsanta.pojo.Product;
    import com.me.secretsanta.validator.ProductValidator;



    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/addProduct.htm")
    public class AddProductController {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("productDAO")
        ProductDAO pdao;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("productValidator")
        ProductValidator validator;

        @InitBinder
        private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
            binder.setValidator(validator);
        }

        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView addProductPage() {

            return new ModelAndView("admin-dashboard", "product", new Product());

        }

        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView saveProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product, BindingResult result) throws Exception {

            String modelObject=null;
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();

            validator.validate(product, result);

            if(result.hasErrors()) {
                return new ModelAndView("admin-dashboard", "product", product);
            }

            Boolean saved = pdao.addProduct(product);
            int count = 1;
            map.put("msgtyp", "add");

            if(saved) {
              map.put("msgfor", "success");
              map.put("rowcount", count);}
            else {
                map.put("msgfor", "error");
                map.put("msg", "Could not save movie");
            }
            return new ModelAndView("resultsView", "map", map);
        }


    }


    _______________________________________________________________________________

    JSP:

    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
            <h1>Please enter the details below :</h1>
            <p>
                <form:form action="${contextPath}/addProduct.htm" commandName="product" method="post">
                    Product Name Title : &emsp; <form:input path="name"/><form:errors path="name"/>
                <br>
                Product Code : &emsp; <form:input path="code"/><form:errors path="code"/>
                <br>
               Product Quantity : &emsp; <form:input path="quantity"/><form:errors path="quantity"/>
                <br>
                Product Price : &emsp; <form:input path="price"/><form:errors path="price"/>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Add Product">
                </form:form>
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
    ________________________________________________________________________________

    Error:

    HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Type Exception Report

    Message java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'product' available as request attribute

    Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

    Exception
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'product' available as request attribute
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:565)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


    Root Cause
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'product' available as request attribute
        org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.admin_002ddashboard_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(admin_002ddashboard_jsp.java:374)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.admin_002ddashboard_jsp._jspService(admin_002ddashboard_jsp.java:166)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


    Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Product Validator:

    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package com.me.secretsanta.validator;

    import com.me.secretsanta.pojo.Product;
    import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
    import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
    import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

    /**
     *
     * @author Sanchit
     */
    public class ProductValidator implements Validator{

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class type) {
    //        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            return type.equals(Movie.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
    //        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "name", "emty-name", "Name cannot be empty");
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "code", "emty-code", "Code cannot be empty");
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "quantity", "emty-quantity", "Quantitycannot be empty");
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "price", "emty-price", "Price cannot be empty");
        }

    }

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

ProductDAO:

package com.me.secretsanta.dao;

import com.me.secretsanta.pojo.Movie;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ProductDAO {

    private static final SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

    public ProductDAO() {

    }



    public Boolean addProduct(Product mv) throws Exception{
        try {

            Session session = sf.openSession();

            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();


            session.save(mv);

            tx.commit();
            session.close();

            return true;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Cannot save object" + ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        } 

    }


    public List<Product> searchProduct(String keyword, String choice) throws Exception{
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
//        Product product;

        String select_query= "from Product where "+choice+"= :"+choice;
//        String select_query= "from Product where name= :name";
        try {

            Session session = sf.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Query q=session.createQuery(select_query);
            q.setString(choice,keyword);
            productList = q.list();
            tx.commit();
            session.close();



        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Cannot retrieve data " + ex.getMessage());
        }   

        return productList;
    }


}
```

Comment: Am not sure what going wrong in your code, looks good. But can you try  change commandName="product" in your form to modelAttribute="product".

Comment: Please show code of ProductDAO and ProductValidator. You might have not applied annotation on these components.

Comment: I have added the code for ProductDAO and ProductValidator as well.